# Finding duplicate Values in dictionary in python and renaming

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dict` in python as below -

```
{'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia', '73535': 'Japan' , '12355': 'Japan', '65447': 'Japan'}
```

The keys are different and unique but there can be common names for Values in the dict. Is there a way where i can find how many common names are there and add a unique number at the end to it ? Like -

```
from random import randint
randint(100, 999)
{'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia345', '73535': 'Japan' , '12355': 'Japan223', '65447': 'Japan789'}
```

The first Value in the common items remains as is, but the other values will be added with a random number at the end - `Russia345, Japan223, Japan789`

I was not able to figure out a way to do this. Should I reverse the dict and write the logic ?

The reason for try this approach is when i send this data to `Grafana` based on Value as value is needed for display, it is showing only one Value in the output, So i wanted to make the Values unique.

Comment: This smells a bit like a workaround. Is there a better way to do this? Worst case scenario, I'd look into uuids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the occurrences of each value:

```
import random
d = {'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia', '73535': 'Japan' , '12355': 'Japan', '65447': 'Japan'}
c, result = {b:[] for b in d.values()}, {}
for a, b in d.items():
   if not c[b]:
     c[b].append('')
     result[a] = b
   else:
     _num = random.randint(100, 999)
     while _num in c[b]:
       _num = random.randint(100, 999)
     c[b].append(_num)
     result[a] = b+str(_num)
```

Output:

```
{'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia513', '73535': 'Japan', '12355': 'Japan383', '65447': 'Japan517'}
```

However, this can be greatly simplified by simply using a counter from `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools
c = {b:itertools.count() for b in d.values()}
result = {a:(lambda x:b if not x else b+str(x))(next(c[b])) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia1', '73535': 'Japan', '12355': 'Japan1', '65447': 'Japan2'}
```

Comment: Ajax -i see an invalid syntax in the line `result = {a:(lambda x:b if not x else f'{b}{x}')(next(c[b])) for a, b in d.items()}`  I'm unable to figure out as i'm trying to understand the command, can you help me with the syntax error

Comment: @sdgd What exactly is raising the syntax error? It works for me, but I am assuming the problem is the `f-string`, which is only available in Python3.7. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: our servers are on `py 2.7`. Your edit fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Before adding a key/value pair to the dict, check if the value is already in the dict, and if so, append something to it.

```
while value in mydict.values():
    value = value + "something"
mydict[key] = value
```

Comment: but this will change the name for the first value as well right ?

Comment: No, because for the very first value, it won't be in the dict yet, so the `while` won't execute.

Comment: Oh yeah!, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the difficulties here is to guarantee that suffixes are random **and** *unique*. The retry method might loop forever. You should rather use `random.shuffle`. We need at most `len(d)-1` random numbers (in the case all keys are mapped to the same value).

```
>>> d = {'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia', '73535': 'Japan' , '12355': 'Japan', '65447': 'Japan'}
>>> import random
>>> L = list(range(1, len(d)))
>>> random.shuffle(L)
>>> L
[3, 1, 5, 4, 2]
```

We will consume those unique random numbers "on demand". We store the value that were seen in a set to avoid duplicates and every time we meet a `seen` key, we pop a suffix from the list:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     if v in seen:
...             d[k] = v+str(L.pop())
...     else:
...             seen.add(v)
...
>>> d
{'1386': 'USA', '23113': 'Russia', '23295': 'Russia2', '73535': 'Japan', '12355': 'Japan4', '65447': 'Japan5'}
```

(Related: [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle))